# CMake Visual Studio Differences?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, cmake

When I went to compile a project with CMake using MSVC++, I noticed something. CMake asked me to identify which copy of Visual Studio I wanted to use, and it presented me with the choices:
Visual C++ 2010
Visual C++ 10
Visual C# 2010
Visual C# 10

What is the difference between 2010 and 10?

Comment: Are you sure CMake asked you that or a popup Visual Studio box? Remember when you first run visual stdio it will ask you a similar question because it wants to adjust some settings to the type of projects you want to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal version number for VS2010 is version 10.  Lucky coincidence.  Version 11 won't be on your machine until 2012.  Or later.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a VS2010 project and compiling it from cmd, these are the options you could use:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 Win64" "%myProject%\src"

CD %HOMEDRIVE%\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

msbuild %myProject%\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /detailedsummary /property:PlatformToolset=v110 /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5.1 /clp:ErrorsOnly /p:Configuration=Debug

msbuild %myProject%\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /detailedsummary /property:PlatformToolset=v110 /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5.1 /clp:ErrorsOnly /p:Configuration=Release
```